# Style an imported styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the following Component:

```
const StyledH3 = styled.h3`
  direction: ${(props) => (props.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')};
`;

const H3 = ({ children }) => (
  <StyledH3 isRTL={isChildrenRTL(children)}>
    {children}
  </StyledH3>
);

export default H3;
```

And I want to extend it's styles, for example in a different file:

```
import { H3 } from 'components';

const Title = styled(H3)`
  background-color: red;
`;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Something like [`Comp.extend`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)?

Comment: @OrB yes, but the extended component is a styled one, but rather a React component that returns a styled component

Comment: @OrB ok, so I found a solution using both the `extend` and `withComponent`. Will publish soon. Thanks man

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to expose the className prop on your exported component so it can receive the new className:

```
const StyledH3 = styled.h3`
    direction: ${(props) => (props.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')};
`;

const H3 = ({ children, className }) => ( // Note - className prop.
    <StyledH3 
        className={className} // Need to add this here 
        isRTL={isChildrenRTL(children)}
    >
        {children}
    </StyledH3>
);
export default H3;
```

Then you can extend your component styles in a different file as you have suggested:

```
import H3 from 'components';

const Title = styled(H3)`
    background-color: red;
`;
```

Reference link https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components

Comment: Tried this and it **didn't** help. `Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As per the `styled-component` documentation you should do it like this.

```
export const StyledH3 = styled.h3`
 direction: ${(props) => (props.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')};
`;
const H3 = ({ children }) => (
  <StyledH3 isRTL={isChildrenRTL(children)}>
    {children}
  </StyledH3>
);
export default H3;
```

And then in your other file where you need it, do something like this.

```
import H3, { StyledH3  } from 'components';

const Title = StyledH3 .extend`
  background-color: red;
`;
```

For reference have a look at the [Extending styles in styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)

Please do note, you can extend a styled-component's style only and not a React dumb component class for `styled-component`.

Comment: What is the H3 component for in your example?

Comment: `H3` is your dumb component, in which you have wrapped `StyledH3` , in your code you were using H3 to extend styled-components. When you should have been using `StyledH3` of your `styled-component`

Comment: so how do I combine the h3 extended styles with the H3 component?

Comment: You can't, that is what I said. It's not possible. You can as I have stated in my answer extend a `styled-component` with another.

Comment: thanks man, but that doesn't solve my use case where need the component logic and the extended styles. I did manage to solve it by combining `extend` and `withComponent` though. Will publish soon. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by utilizing both `extend` and [`withComponent`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent)  methods. So instead of exporting the component I ended up exporting the styled component with all the logic inside it:

```
const TwoWayP = styled.p`
  direction: ${props => isChildrenRTL(props.children) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' };
`;
```

and then extend the styled component and if needed (and I need) change it's tag:

```
const TwoWayH3 = TwoWayP.withComponent('h3');

const Title = TwoWayH3.extend`
  background-color: red;
`;
```

So the main part of my solution was to move the logic inside the styled component without a React component

Comment: Note from docs: *`"As of styled-components v4 the withComponent API is now a candidate for deprecation."`*

Answer (score 0):

### Using *styled-components* `v4` ["as"](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) :

#### h3.js

```
const StyledH3 = styled.h3`
  color:red;
`;

export const H3 = ({ children }) => (
  <StyledH3>{children}</StyledH3>
);
```

#### card.js

```
import { H3 } from 'components';

const Title = styled.div`
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
`;

export const Card = (props) => (
  <div>
     <Title as={H3} />   <----- using "as" --------
     <p>...</p>
  </div>
);
```